# SoundCloud API data is retrieved in debugger but not when just run

Tags: javascript, debugging, soundcloud, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to extract user data using SoundCloud's available API. When I run the code, nothing appears in LocalStorage; however, when I run the code through the debugger, all the necessary key values are generated and added to LocalStorage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  SC.initialize({
      client_id: '40b9cd8db2848eedd9dce3381b51916f',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8000/callback.html'
  });

  $('.btn-instagram').click(function(){
      SC.connect(function() {
          SC.get('/me', function(data) {
              var userData = {"id": data.id, "username": data.username, "permalink_url": data.permalink_url, "avatar_url": data.avatar_url, "full_name": data.full_name, "country": data.country, "city": data.city, "description": data.description, "track_count": data.track_count, "followers_count": data.followers_count, "followings_count": data.followings_count, "private_tracks_count": data.private_tracks_count}
              localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
              SC.get('/users/' + data.id + '/tracks/', function(tracks) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
                    console.log(tracks[i].title);
                    localStorage.setItem(tracks[i].title, JSON.stringify({"id": tracks[i].id, "title": tracks[i].title, "permalink_url": tracks[i].permalink_url, "artwork_url": tracks[i].artwork_url, "label_name": tracks[i].label_name, "release_day": tracks[i].release_day, "release_month": tracks[i].release_month, "release_year": tracks[i].release_year, "comment_count": tracks[i].comment_count, "download_count": tracks[i].download_count, "playback_count": tracks[i].playback_count, "favoritings_count": tracks[i].favoritings_count}))
                  }
              });
          });
          window.location = "dashboardindex.html";
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Button click function was giving me problems.